# DHCP server for a Network Manager bridge connection using dnsmasq-base?

Tags: ubuntu, networkmanager, dhcp, dnsmasq

With Ubuntu 22.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4 I bridged (`br0`) the connections for ethernet (`eth0`) and WiFi (`wlan0`) using `nmcli`. That seemed to work fine, with WiFi acting as an access point.

When I used the access point feature/connection that ships with Ubuntu though I notice that `dnsmasq` starts running and handing out addresses, but I don't know what's starting it and why — my own connections don't start any DHCP server.

What aspect of a network manager connection makes sure this `dnsmasq` instance is starting? Can I use the same mechanism to serve DHCP on my bridge connection? I did put my config file in the `dnsmasq` config directory, but it won't do much use if the server doesn't start.

The full `dnsmasq` package is not installed — only `dnsmasq-base`. Can it be accomplished without the full package?